# Center pie chart in a box

Tags: shinydashboard

I am drawing a pie chart in a box on shiny dashboard through plot_ly. Not able to get it in the center of the box.

```
layout(xaxis = list(title = MVNO",align='center', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list( showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE , showticklabels = FALSE))
```